# Decrease distance between point in highchart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm tryng to decrease distance between data points on the chart below code is from highcharts example

```
$(function () {
$(document).ready(function() {
    Highcharts.setOptions({
        global: {
            useUTC: false
        }
    });

    var chart;
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'spline',
            animation: Highcharts.svg, // don't animate in old IE
            marginRight: 5,
            events: {
                load: function() {

                    // set up the updating of the chart each second
                    var series = this.series[0];
                    setInterval(function() {
                        var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
                            y = Math.random();
                        series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
                    }, 1000);
                }
            }
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Live random data'
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            tickPixelInterval: 50 // here i wanted to decerease bu it does not work
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Value'
            },
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 0.1,
                color: '#808080'
            }]
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                    return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
                    Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', this.x) +'<br/>'+
                    Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2);
            }
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        exporting: {
            enabled: false
        },
        series: [{ // series with random data
            name: 'Random data', // may be here 
            data: (function() {
                // generate an array of random data
                var data = [],
                    time = (new Date()).getTime(),
                    i;

                for (i = -19; i <= 0; i++) {
                    data.push({
                        x: time + i * 1000,
                        y: Math.random()
                    });
                }
                return data;
            })()
        }]
    });
});

  });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/V9BV4/

Is it possible to make? I need to zoom out xAxis or decrease distance between dots on line

Comment: Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/V9BV4/1/ ? Simply use min/maxPadding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do what you're asking, you may wish to consider:

1) Making the chart smaller so the individual points are closer together (see http://jsfiddle.net/brightmatrix/Gq9X9/):

```
chart: {
    vtype: 'spline',
    width: 300,     /* make this value anything you want */
    animation: Highcharts.svg, // don't animate in old IE
    marginRight: 5,
    ...
```

This is similar to the suggestion @falconw offered above.

2) In this specific real-time example, change how your data is being computed so that you're pushing out more points each time the chart is updated (see http://jsfiddle.net/brightmatrix/Fp5K4/):

```
series: [{
    name: 'Random data',
    data: (function() {
        // generate an array of random data
            var data = [],
            time = (new Date()).getTime(),
            i;
            for (i = -19; i <= 0; i++) {
                data.push({
                    /* made the multiplier larger so points are closer together */
                    x: time + i * 10000,    
                    y: Math.random()
                });
            }
        return data;
    })()
}]
```

Bottom line, either change your chart dimensions or make your data "denser," so the points are closer together. I hope this helps.